# Vscode Folding Area

Tags: visual-studio-code, folding

Normal editor folding staying left side of html editor. But it did happen I don't know, it folding area moved to up of editor. So How I can fixed it ?

[image]

Thank you for helping...

**Edit 1**

I thought my problem was caused by this but my problem is like that,
there is folding in left side of editor. it's hiding in few second only vue template. It's working normal html files. How can I do like as below ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to folding. The thing is called "breadcrumbs", and can be disabled using:

```
"breadcrumbs.enabled": false
```

Comment: thank you for answer . 
Yes, you're right.I thought my problem was caused by this but my problem is like that 
when it's breadcrumbs visible left folding hiding

https://imgur.com/BowZ7d5

Answer (score 0):

I found solution,
I was using vetur extention. and Vetur published new version which is **0.27.1** and it's not working very well. I installed previous version it's fixed.